Alphabet of Turing Machines and Diagonalization
When we are using a diagonalization argument, does it matter what the alphabet of the Turing machine we are using to do the diagonalization is? I think it does but I'm not 100% sure.
For example, suppose the language of encoding of deciders $\{\langle M_1\rangle, \langle M_2\rangle, ...\}$ is Turing-recognizable. We can prove that there is a decider not in the language via diagonalization.
I think the first proof is correct, but not the second or third, although I have seen the second and third proof being used.

Given an enumeration of the deciders in the set $\{\langle M_1\rangle, \langle M_2\rangle, ...\}$, we pick a fixed alphabet, say $\{0,1\}^*$. We enumerate the strings in this alphabet by its standard order. Let there be a TM $D$ such that, for any string $s_i$, $D$ accepts $s_i$ if either $s_i$ contains a character not in the alphabet of $M_i$, or $M_i$ rejects $s_i$. Otherwise, $D$ rejects $s_i$.
Given the same enumeration of deciders and strings, $D$ accepts iff $M_i$ rejects.
Given the same enumeration of deciders, we enumerate all strings on standard order, and let $D$ accepts iff $M_i$ rejects.

2 seems incorrect to me because if $M_i$ is undefined for $s_i$, then $D$ is undefined for $s_i$. So $D$ might not be a decider. Additionally, 3 seems wrong because there are no standard order of all strings when there are infinitely many symbols.
